# WP Bakery Page Builder Role Manager doesn't save Disable Classic Editor

Tags: mysql, wordpress, editor, wordpress-gutenberg

After the Wordpress 5.0.2 update I had to also update the WP Bakery editor. It has the option to disable the Guntenberg editor and also on the Roles Manager tab it has the option for disabling the Classic Editor.

After playing around a bit I saw that once the Classic Editor is disabled by checking the box on Roles Manager tab, the system doesn't record any other inputs on that field, e.g. it cant be enabled again. All other options work fine when selected and saved.

In all cases when saved a blank page apper with the message:

```
{"message":"Roles settings successfully saved."}
```

Tried to find WP Bakery settings stored in the DB but to no success yet.

Any tips on how to solve this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately not yet.